# if statements in while loop?

Tags: php, loops, if-statement, while-loop

Hi I am just wondering how do if statements work in while (loop)?
I want the page to display number through 1 to 10 and show special comment for number 1 and 2.
Thanks so much!

```
<?php
$x = 1;
while ($x <= 10) {
    echo "". $x . "<br />";
    $x = $x + 1; 
}

if ($x = 1 ) {
    echo "" . $comment . "";
    $comment = "this is one!";
} elseif ($x = 2) {
    echo "" . $comment . "";
    $comment = "this is two!";
}
?>
```

Comment: Simply wrap the `while` loop around the conditions. Also you are echoing before declaring` $comment`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - you need to make sure that your `IF` conditions are inside your while loop. Also, you should read up on the difference between a single equals sign and a double equals (in this case, you want the double equals `==` as you're testing for equality).

My take on your code would be something like the following:

```
<?php
$x = 1;
while( $x <= 10) {
    $comment = "";

    if ($x == 1 ) {
        $comment = "This is one!";
    }

    if ($x == 2) {
        $comment = "This is two!";
    }


    echo $x . " " . $comment . "<br />\n";
    $x = $x + 1; 
}
```

This yields:

```
1 This is one!<br />
2 This is two!<br />
3 <br />
4 <br />
5 <br />
6 <br />
7 <br />
8 <br />
9 <br />
10 <br />
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked perfectly (:P just that closing php ?> was forgotten but its all good haha thanks so muchhhhhh)

Comment: No problems. Also, PHP doesn't necessarily require you to have a closing `?>` - it depends on whether or not you have any HTML coming after.

Comment: Since `$x` is your number, you'd want to show $x multiplied by two. So the output line would be changed to: `echo ($x * 2) . " " . $comment . "<br />\n";`

Comment: @meowwwwww *"just that closing php ?> was forgotten"* - If you've nothing below that or there's no HTML, you don't need the `?>`. It's actually best to leave it out if there's no HTML and if ever you use a class. I hardly ever close it off, if I've no HTML following below.

Answer (score 0):

Actually '=' is an assignment operator and not a conditional operator You have to use '==' in the if and elseif statements. and also initialize the $comment before you use it.

```
 if ($x == 1 ) {
       $comment = "this is one!";
       echo "".$comment."";
  }     
  elseif ($x == 2) {
       $comment = "this is two!";
       echo "".$comment."";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete the previous answers... if you know how many iterations you want to do, we prefer using a "for". Try this :

```
<?php

For( $i = 0 ; $i < 10 ; $i++ ){

   $comment = "";

   if( $i == 1 ) $comment = "One";

   if( $i == 2 ) $comment = "Two"; 

   echo "Page: " . $i . " -> Comment: " . $comment . "\n";

}

?>
```

Comment: Hi I was just going to ask about FOR statement!!!! thanks!! What should I do if I want it to display numbers that double every time? like display 2, 4, 6 ...? Thank you soooooo much!

Comment: If you want to display 2, 4, 6 but do all iterations... you can use the modulo : % Like this: `if( $i%2 == 0) echo $i;` If you want to do the loop only for 2, 4, 6, ... change the loop like this `for($i=0;$i<10;$i+2)`